# Python/CSV: opening CSV file in function as DictReader is not working (int object)

Tags: python, csv

I want to open a csv-file in a python function as DictReader and then make it into a list.
Doing this in the ipython shell works fine.
However, if I try to call a function that should do exactly the same, I get:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

```
def get_all(pathtofile):
    mctable = csv.DictReader(open(pathtofile), delimiter='\t') 
    for x in mctable:
        print x
```

shell:

```
    In [77]: get_all('amaecht.csv')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-a467058ba260> in <module>()
----> 1 get_all('amaecht.csv')

/getmc.py in get_all(mclist)
      3         mctable=csv.DictReader(open(pathtofile), delimiter='\t') 
      4         for x in mctable:
----> 5                 print x

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: By any chance, is `amaecht.csv` inside the same directory as the module calling it? Also `'int' object is not iterable` is basically what it means: you are returning an integer for `mctable`.

Comment: Could you please print the content of `mctable`?

Comment: Are you sure the code you have shown us is the code that gave you the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this it worked for me when 
hope it will be helpful to you aswell

```
   file = open('/Desktop/d.csv', "r")
   csv_file =csv.reader(file.read().splitlines())


   header = ['title','price' ]
   for row in csv_file:
       params = dict(zip(header, row))
```